# Steps to create a chooser dialog using intent.createChooser() in android

Tags: java, android

I want to create an app where I want to pop-up the Chooser dialog for all messenger apps.
I want to know how Intent can be used in such cases. And, where all we need to make changes in order to use intent.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have  a look on this link : https://google-developer-training.gitbooks.io/android-developer-fundamentals-course-concepts/content/en/Unit%201/23_c_activities_and_implicit_intents.html

Comment: *I want to create an app* -> then do it and come back when you have real specific programming issues. Feel free to try things on your own and read the docs as well.